# Copy the last row ONLY from a Sheet and paste it to another sheets last row

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

The code I have copies all rows from first sheet and paste it to the last row on the other sheet.

I have tried some other other suggestions but now of them worked with the code that I have and it broke my original code had to rewrite.

1.Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A

```
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

2.Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A

```
   'Offset property moves down 1 row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

3.Copy & Paste Data

```
  wsCopy.Range("A2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
          wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
```

I want the last row on wsCopy ONLY to be paste to next available row on wsDest. I keep getting all rows from wsCopy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wsCopy.Range("A" & lCopyLastRow & ":H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
      wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
```

or

```
wsCopy.Rows(lCopyLastRow).Range("A1:H1").Copy _
      wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)'Range A1:H1 here is *relative* to the row
```

or

```
wsCopy.Cells(lCopyLastRow, "A").Resize(1, 8).Copy _
      wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
```

Comment: When I use the wsCopy.Cells(lCopyLastRow, "A").Resize(1, 8).Copy I get a compile error -  in my next line of code ... wsDest.Range ("A" & lDestLastRow) - The ".Range" highlighted.

Comment: I used you first suggestion it worked great. Thank you!